# titanium android custom theme no window actionbar

Tags: android, xml, titanium

I've an android app written using titanium sdk. the new sdk (`3.5.0GA`) changed things about managing the default window title and actionbar behaviour.

the [official blog offers 3 ways](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/08/hiding-the-android-actionbar/) to solve this problem ([official doc](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Themes-section-34636181_AndroidThemes-CustomThemes)):

the first solution (`$.index.activity.actionBar.hide();`) has a problem: the actionbar is shown for a while before being hidden. that animation is not what I want.

the second solution would be better if I can make it works (`customtheme.xml`)

my situation is as follows:

tiapp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <manifest>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <application android:theme="@style/MyTheme"/>
        <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <application android:largeHeap="true"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

/platform/android/res/values/customtheme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

the same thing done with a plain android studio project, does the magic.

**actually, the error I got, is**

```
[ERROR] :  /Users/dariorusignuolo/Desktop/titanium-cocktailsmachine/CM/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen').
```

it seems to me that the App compat library is missing (I have installed the android support library `v 21.0.3`)

I don't know how to solve my problem. anybody knows?

ps.
didn't try the third option, but just want to make the second one works. less code lines...

Comment: check [this answer](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178261/how-to-use-android-theme-light-notitlebar-#answer-282945)

Comment: [ERROR] :  /Users/dariorusignuolo/Desktop/titanium-cocktailsmachine/CM/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen').



it seems it can't find the appcompat library (which I already installed the android support library via the sdk manager)

Comment: I see no parent attribute in style tag, add something like `<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">`

Comment: after your comment, I modified my customtheme.xml with parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" but same error.

Comment: are you able to see normal actionbar without applying you custom theme ?

Comment: yes. I've not deleted the 1st solution ($.index.activity.actionBar.hide(); on window load)

Comment: how to install the compat themes on android for titanium?

Comment: the process to install compat themes for titanium is the same; i.e installing them from Android SDK manager( "Android Support Library" and " Android Support Repository" ).

Answer (score 2):

the solution to solve my problem was to (thanks to turle for the help):

in the platform/res/values/MyTheme.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and to edit the manifest through the tiapp.xml this way

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
        <application android:theme="@style/MyTheme"/>
    </manifest> 
</android>
```

maybe you that encountered this problem should project -> clean to see the theme been applied

hope this helps